# ElasticSearch DateHistogram Aggregation Fill Missing Data

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to use ElasticSearch spring data for some aggregations

Here Is my query

```
final FilteredQueryBuilder filteredQuery = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),
      FilterBuilders.andFilter(FilterBuilders.termFilter("gender", "F"),
      FilterBuilders.termFilter("place", "Arizona"),
      FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("dob").from(from).to(to)));

final MetricsAggregationBuilder<?> aggregateArtifactcount = AggregationBuilders.sum("delivery")
            .field("birth");

    final AggregationBuilder<?> dailyDateHistogarm =
       AggregationBuilders.dateHistogram(AggregationConstants.DAILY).field("dob")
        .interval(DateHistogram.Interval.DAY).subAggregation(aggregateArtifactcount);

    final SearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withIndices(index).withTypes(type)
        .withQuery(filteredQuery).addAggregation(dailyDateHistogarm).build();

    return elasticsearchTemplate.query(query, new DailyDeliveryAggregation());
```

Also this is my Aggregation

```
        public class DailyDeliveryAggregation implements ResultsExtractor<List<DailyDeliverySum>> {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<DailyDeliverySum> extract(final SearchResponse response) {
    final List<DailyDeliverySum> dailyDeliverySum = new ArrayList<DailyDeliverySum>();
    final Aggregations aggregations = response.getAggregations();
    final DateHistogram daily = aggregations.get(AggregationConstants.DAILY);
    final List<DateHistogram.Bucket> buckets = (List<DateHistogram.Bucket>) daily.getBuckets();
    for (final DateHistogram.Bucket bucket : buckets) {
        final Sum sum = (Sum) bucket.getAggregations().getAsMap().get("delivery");
        final int deliverySum = (int) sum.getValue();
        final int delivery = (int) bucket.getDocCount();
        final String dateString = bucket.getKeyAsText().string();
        dailyDeliverySum.add(new DailyDeliverySum(deliverySum, delivery, dateString));
    }
    return dailyDeliverySum;
}
}
```

It gives me the correct data , But It doesn't satisfy all my needs 
Suppose if I query for  time range of 10 days , If there is no data for  a date in the given time range It miss that date in Date histogram buckets ,But I want to set 0 as default value for aggregation and doc count if there is no data available

Is there any way to do it ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the ["minimum document count" feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_3) of the `date_histogram` aggregation and set it to 0. That way, you'll also get buckets that don't contain any data:

```
final AggregationBuilder<?> dailyDateHistogarm =
   AggregationBuilders.dateHistogram(AggregationConstants.DAILY)
        .field("dob")        
        .minDocCount(0)                          <--- add this line
        .interval(DateHistogram.Interval.DAY)
        .subAggregation(aggregateArtifactcount);
```

Comment: i need to add  .extendedBounds(from, to)  along with .minDocCount(0) to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Example from @Val by itself did not work for me (I'm using the high-level API with ElasticSearch 6.2.x). What did work though, was telling that the aggregation should handle missing values as 0:

```
final AggregationBuilder<?> dailyDateHistogarm =
AggregationBuilders.dateHistogram(AggregationConstants.DAILY)
    .field("dob")        
    .minDocCount(0)                          
    .missing(0)
    .interval(DateHistogram.Interval.DAY)
    .subAggregation(aggregateArtifactcount);
```